# Can I run git tools against a remote repo?

Tags: ssh, git

I'm working on a project on a server machine where git is not available. This is likely not going to change in a close future. I wonder if it is possible to use my local installation of git to work on a repository on the server through SSH, for example, doing things like:

```
git add -A --target ssh://user@server.com/my/repo
```

Note: I understand "remote repo" is a bad choice of words since the term has a meaning in git but I hope you understand what I mean.

The server is running SunOS 5.10 and is using pkg.

Comment: You can simply install git on the remote server with user rights. That turns your *pseudo-remote* repo into a real repository that can be used from you local machine like any other remote repo via SSH.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to gain administration access to the machine in order to install Git, you will not be able to use Git on the computer until the (at minimum) core utilities are installed.

Comment: That's not correct. Git does not need administrator privileges. Being ordinary user is totally sufficient.

Comment: You'd still need super user privileges to *install* it though, but not to use it.

Comment: No, you don't. Configure it with `--prefix=/home/someuser/.local` and  after that `make && make install` runs fine as a user. That works also on SunOS 5.10, I have done it!

Comment: @Marco Out of interest then, should that work on any Linux-based box?

Comment: Yes. If the sysadmin didn't configure an extraordinarily strict environment (e.g. `noexec` on the partition) this works on SunOS, Linux, FreeBSD and all other Unix systems (if a compiler is installed).

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't even have build tools on the machine.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to install git on the remote machine. That way you can use the repository in the same way as any other repository via SSH.

You don't need admin privileges to install git. Simple use `--prefix=<some_dir>` where you have write access in `<some_dir>`:

```
./configure --prefix=/home/me/.local
make
make install
```

And make sure `/home/me/.local/bin` is in your PATH.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't even have build tools on the machine.